# Minimise function with single minimum and no maximums

Tags: f#

I'm learning F#. I wrote a function to minimise a function with a single minimum and no maximums. At the bottom I test it on Math.Cos.

What do you think? I've wrote it pretty much as I would in an imperative language. Could it be done more functionally?

```
/// <summary>Assuming f is a continuous function with a single minimum and 
/// no maximums in (lower,upper), find the minimum point.</summary>
let rec minimise f (lower:float) (upper:float) =
    let lmid = (2.0*lower+upper)/3.0
    let umid = (lower+2.0*upper)/3.0
    if lmid = lower && umid = upper then
        Seq.minBy f [lower; upper]
    else if f lmid < f umid then      
        minimise f lower umid
    else
        minimise f lmid upper

let solution = minimise Math.Cos 0.0 6.0
printf "solution: %g" solution
printf "absolute error: %g" (solution - Math.PI)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty functional.

The only thing I'd recommend is to avoid comparing floating-point numbers for exact match. Because arithmetic happens in binary, not in decimal, multiplying and dividing by nice-looking decimal numbers will produce ugly-looking binary ones, and more importantly, lose precision. As a result, depending on the input, your terminating condition may literally *never become true* - e.g. `lmid` may come out just a bit higher than `lower` at every step, and your function will recurse indefinitely.

The bottom line is, you can't trust direct comparison of floating-point numbers. Instead, compare their difference with a very small number (aka "margin of error"). But even then, you can't just use a constant for this, because you never know if it will be "small enough" for the inputs. The accepted way of doing this is to use a fraction of the inputs - aka "relative margin of error" (as opposed to "absolute").

```
 if x = y ...  // bad
 if abs (x-y) <= 0.00001 ... // better
 if abs (x-y) <= (abs x * 0.00001) ... // even better
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks pretty good to me. A few little tips:

- The type annotations on the `lower` and `upper` parameters are not strictly necessary since they would be inferred by the compiler from usage. However, you may prefer to be explicit and keep them there.
- You can write `elif` instead of `else if`.
- The `<summary>` tags are not necessary in your doc comment. They are added in automatically. You only need them if if you also want to use other tags like `<param>`.